# Which kind of explicit conversion is done here?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is the code that compile and works in my MVS2015:

```
#define STRING_TEST "Test String"

using namespace std;

void test(char * str) {
    cout << str;
}

int main ()
{
    test(STRING_TEST);
}
```

I guess that STRING_TEST was converted into a char[11]. Instead, since I pass it without `&`, it creates a char * pointer? Or what am I missing?

Comment: `STRING_TEST` is a macro. It doesn't get "converted", it gets *substituted* with its replacement text.

Comment: why the macro? It would be exactly the same to write `test("Test String");`

Comment: You need to enable more compiler warnings, this is not legal C++[11 and later] and deprecated in C++98/03.

Comment: the type of variable passed is still "const char*" .

Comment: @BaummitAugen, why its not legal?

Comment: Note, a string literal is of type `const char[]`, conversion to `char*` is dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: @dd2 Because the standard says so. vOv

Comment: I think that there's a good explanation on c++ preprocessor [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work).

Comment: [Does not compile](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9t908JG7EL2o31g3) on a real C++ compiler.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Fair enough mr.Tree, edited just for you.

Comment: @KerrekSB Turbo C++ is a real compiler... :)

Comment: @GillBates: It may be a real compiler (see below), but it's not a real C++ compiler. It compiles something that was called C++ in 1989 when it was first loaded onto the DOS emulator it requires to run, but when we say C++ now we mean ISO C++, which didn't even _exist_ until ten years later!! Is a thing still "real" if it doesn't work on platforms created within the 1990s, 2000s, 2010s?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is anything real? ( no but really, the 2006 version doesn't )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Test string"` is of type `const char[12]`, not `char[11]` (you forgot `'\0'`).

Your code is equivalent to

```
test("Test String");
```

<sub>Macros just do a find+replace, so it's not "converted".</sub>

Arrays decay into pointers, to here, the char arrays decays into `char*`. And so `test` calls it. This however is has been removed as of C++, since `const char* != char*`.

Comment: Actually it is `const char[12]`, and this is illegal on more updated compilers.

Comment: Hello my function I have an array, take my variable and give it play. It works I think without delay but woe is me we have decay.

Comment: @paizza When a pointer is asked and an array is passed, yes, always. (except on sundays but that's personal).

Comment: But If I do this `const char kSamplerDefaultPath[] = "Test String";` instead of #define, it doenst work anymore :(

Comment: @paizza Because a `const char*` is not a `char*`.

Comment: arrays decay into pointers?: Pretty much always.  The exceptions are 1) when passed to `sizeof`; 2) when initializing a value which is a reference to an array of the right size (and I always have to look up the syntax for defining one of those).

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit conversion at all in your code.

`STRING_TEST` is a macro, so the statement

```
test(STRING_TEST);
```

is preprocessed into

```
test("Test String");
```

which will then be compiled.

`"Test String"` is a string literal, so when passed to a function will be IMPLICITLY converted to a `const char *`.

So, assuming your compiler complies with the standard, the statement will not compile (since implicit conversion from `const char *` (or from a string literal to `char *`) is not permitted.

However, some compilers do allow this implicit conversion (for reasons of backward compatibility to older versions of C).   Those compilers can often be made to complain by cranking up diagnostics (e.g. with Microsoft compilers adding the `/Wall` command line option).

Comment: I don't get an error on VS 2015 with `/Wall` for this.

Comment: Ah, well, bad luck.   Often != always.

Comment: I think you are mistaken.  The standard specifies an implicit conversion from  string literal to `char *` (no const).  This conversion is deprecated, and obviously it is UB to modify the characters through the pointer.

Comment: Looks like C++14 has removed that - but I'm pretty sure it used to be there.

Comment: @MartinBonner: It was indeed. Deprecated in C++98 and C++03; removed in C++11. Non-existent therefore in C++14.